# Getting residue number and residue name in Biopython PDB module

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm currently using pymol's iterate to get all the residue numbers, and then I use those to retrieve the residue name. I don't think that's the best way to do it. I tried to look for a way in biopython to no avail. I would appreciate your input and suggestions.

A side question, sometimes even chain[i].resname gives me a KeyError: (' ', 'number', ' ') with a certain residue, which made me use a try and except block. Any alternatives?

```
from Bio import *
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import PPBuilder
structure = PDBParser().get_structure('5bmy', '5bmy.pdb')    
model = structure[0]
chain = model['A']

import __main__
__main__.pymol_argv = ['pymol','-qc']
import pymol
from pymol import cmd, stored
pymol.finish_launching()
cmd.load('5bmy.pdb')  # use the name of your pdb file
stored.residues = []
cmd.iterate('name ca', 'stored.residues.append(resi)')
numbers = [ int(x) for x in stored.residues ]
for i in numbers:
    print (chain[i].resname)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you may want to also post this on biostars, they have a more active community for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the API (and at what is available to chain via the command `dir(chain)`), I can see that there is a method `get_residues()`. Looking at one of the residues contained, I can see that there is a function `get_resname()`. Using these, one solution for you problem might be:

```
from Bio import *
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import PPBuilder
structure = PDBParser().get_structure('5bmy', '5bmy.pdb')    


model = structure[0]
chain = model['A']

for i in chain.get_residues():
    print(i.get_resnames())
```

This gives a solution that doesn't need `pymol`.